# Django GET parameters redirect

Tags: django

I'm in process of migrating my website to Django cms. But there is a problem with the URL's with GET parameters in CMS module which has been deleted in the current site. They are still live in Google.Webmasters.

When I go to site.com?foo=0&bar=1517 it will open index page without any redirects.

Any GET parameters could spawn a duplicate page.
I think it is bad for the SEO, because now I have bunch of duplicate urls for the index page.

I want to redirect all urls with get parameters from the root to my root index, ex:

```
site.com?foo=0&bar=1234
site.com?foo=12&bar=1234&baz=123
site.com?foo=12

  redirect(301) to:

to site.com/
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want ite.com?catid=0&id=1517 to be redirected to `site.com/0/1517`?

Comment: No, it should redirect to site.com/

Comment: Is it only the root URL you want to do this for? Or do you also want eg `site.com/foo?catid=0` to redirect to `site.com/foo`?

Comment: I want it for the root URL only

Comment: If you want remove all the parameters from any urls/specific url - do this on web server side. Do not pass these parameters to the Django backend at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the beginning of your index view:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
if request.GET.get('foo') or request.GET.get('bar'):
        return redirect('/')
```